# Warning: Error during font loading: Maximum call stack size exceeded error with PDFJS on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to load a pdf using PDFJS on my rails app. 
Only images are loaded, while any text are not rendered.

The console says:

```
Warning: Error during font loading: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Weirdly, it works perfectly on localhost and on Firefox.
It works on any browser on localhost. The error only arise at production server.

Here is my config.

application.js

```
//= require compatibility
//= require pdf
//= require pdf_viewer
//= require simpleviewer
```

simpleviewer.js.erb

```
$(function(){

  'use strict';

  if (!PDFJS.PDFViewer || !PDFJS.getDocument) {
    alert('Please build the library and components using\n' +
          '  `node make generic components`');
  }

  PDFJS.workerSrc = "<%= asset_path('pdf.worker.js') %>";

  $('[data-type=pdf]').each(function(){
    var pdfUrl =$(this).attr('data-url');
    var container = $(this).find('#viewerContainer')[0];
    renderPdf(pdfUrl,container)
  })

  function renderPdf(pdfUrl, container){
    var pdfLinkService = new PDFJS.PDFLinkService();
    var pdfViewer = new PDFJS.PDFViewer({
      container: container,
      linkService: pdfLinkService,
    });
    pdfLinkService.setViewer(pdfViewer);

    container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
      pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';
    });

    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfUrl).then(function (pdfDocument) {
      pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);
      pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument, null);
    });
  }
})
```

pdf_show.erb

```
<div class="pdf_show" data-type="pdf" data-url="#{pdf_url}">
  <div id="viewerContainer">
    <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everyone mentioned that the error is due to chrome unable to properly read the minified code. I tried to selectively disable rails asset compressor but failed.

So for workaround,I use this cdn .
I dont know if this is an official CDN though.

```
https://npmcdn.com/pdfjs-dist@1.4.79/build/pdf.combined.js
```

Update: The cdn I am using is using fake worker and not minified, and I couldn't find any other cdn for pdfjs. So I hosted the minified pdf.js and pdf.worker.js on AWS S3 and use it as my own cdn.

Comment: By doing the above you are: 1) disabling web worker (it means browser might throw "long running scripts" dialogs); 2) still not compressing the code.

Comment: yeah, you are right @async5. So now I host minified pdf.js and pdf.worker.js on S3 and use it as cdn. Its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7044, it is an issue with Chrome running Uglified code. There is a workaround you can use: apply `{compress: {sequences: false}}` options (see [source](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/b2828858ed2673fa1d4b6c8edc9290149597f193/make.js#L709)) or disable JS compression. (You can also report the issue to Chrome bug tracking system).

Comment: New version of Uglify will have a fix for that https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1038